# error C2248 cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, friend-function

We got an exercise in c++. The teacher gave us the functions in the public part of the "class Assignment"(so I cannot change the public declaration of the functions in the header.h). I got an compilation error when i tried to make a friend cout function: the compiler say "Error  4   error C2248: 'biumath::Assignment::m_rowsOfVarArray' : cannot access private member declared in class 'biumath::Assignment'". I thinks that the problem is with the namespaces.

biumath.h

```
#ifndef BIUMATH_H
    #define BIUMATH_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    //using namespace std;

    namespace biumath
    {
    class Assignment
    {
    private:
        int **m_varArray;
        int m_rowsOfVarArray;
    public:
         Assignment(); //1
         Assignment(char symbol, double value); //2
         bool containsValueFor(char symbol) const; //3
         double valueOf(char symbol) const; //4
         void add(char symbol, double val); //5
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out,
            const Assignment& assignment); //6
        };
    }
    #endif
```

biumath.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "biumath.h"
using namespace biumath;
using namespace std;
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out,
        const Assignment& assignment)
{
        out<<assignment.m_rowsOfVarArray<<std::endl;
        //return the stream. cout print the stream result.
        return out;
}
```

again I cannot change the public part of the class. thanks!

Comment: And what is YOUR question?

Comment: why I cannot access the private member. I declared the function as a friend function

Comment: @jhkhjkhjkjhhj: As explained in the duplicate, you've declared the friend to be in `namespace biumath`, then defined a different function in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message explains the problem. The property `m_rowsOfVarArray` is declared as `private`, which means you cannot read from it or write to it outside of the class. To fix this, you need to change it to `public` or write an accessor function to retrieve the value.

Comment: As I said I cannot chane the declaration of the public part of the class. and I can get to the private part, because the function is a friend funciton.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write or use a `public` method in order to change your variable.
You use `private` to avoid any unexpected or unauthorised change of your variables. So, that only your `public` method is able to change it properly.